# How to Open the Profile Management Window Every Time You Open Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, icons, .desktop

Chrome allows multiple people to use Chrome on the same computer, with each profile having its own custom bookmarks, settings, and themes. By default,  Chrome opens to the profile used the last time the browser was opened.

I do not want that to happen. I want to see this screen whenever I launch Chrome.

[image: Manage Profile Screen]

It's Fairly easy to do in Windows, How can I do it in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a desktop file:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/My-Chrome.desktop
```

Copy paste the following to it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Chrome my profile
Terminal=false
Name=My Chrome
Exec=google-chrome --profile-directory="Guest Profile"
Type=Application
Icon=google-chrome
Name[en_US]=My Chrome
```

Save it.

Named it "My Chrome" to differentiate from the regular Chrome launcher.

Now look for "My Chrome" and click on it.

You can also open it from Terminal with the command line:

```
google-chrome --profile-directory="Guest Profile"
```